# Using jspdf-autoTable margin top a gap is coming between two table

Tags: jspdf, jspdf-autotable

Using `jspdf-autoTable 3.1.1` and `jspdf 1.5.3`, why a gap is coming between two autotables passing margin object :

First Table:

```
margin: {top: 10, right: 14, bottom: 0, left: 14}
```

Second Table:

```
margin: {top: 20, right: 14, bottom: 0, left: 14}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user3837868 Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: Does anyone else face this problem? Any suggestions are appreciable

Comment: @Simon Bengtsson any help is appreciable

Answer (score 1):

you can use this option:

startY:50